# When is the TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener exactly fired?

Tags: java, android, events, android-studio

I am creating an Android application, and I am trying to use a TimePicker inside of it. I am trying to understand when exactly the OnTimeChangedListener is fired. I have this code inside of my onCreate method:

```
TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener timeChangedListener =
            new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener(){

                @Override
                public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                 // My code is here...
                }
            };
```

I tried putting a breakpoint inside that block, but the program seems to never reach it. Here's the code in the XML layout for time picker:

```
<TimePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/time_picker"></TimePicker>
```

Should it get fired as soon as the user changes something in the TimePicker? Or does it wait till he enters hour, minute and AM or PM. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener.html)

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = 
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
                int selectedMinute) {

             // your logic 

        }
    };
```

Comment: Okay, it works. But now it is like a pop up. Is there anyway you add text to it? because this way the user won't know what he is supposed to enter the time for. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't get you what you are saying.

Comment: What I mean is I need to display the time picker with text next to it, so the user knows what he is supposed to do. Because right now the way it is, the user will just get a dialog to select time, but he doesn't know what he's supposed to do. Thanks for replying

Comment: So you want text with Timepicker dialog?

Comment: Yes, and sorry for any confusion I caused.

Comment: You can create Dialog and add TimePicker Widget (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should get it by looking at the `interface`

```
imePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute
```

it has hourOfDay and minute and the View itself..